# How to use redis as a module within a nodejs aplication?

Tags: javascript, node.js, caching, redis

I'm implementing a cache mechanism on my app using redis. I'm using `redis ^4.0.2`.

My app is organized like this:

```
 - index.js
 -- routes
    -- users.js
 -- controllers
    -- users.js
 -- models
    -- user.js
 -- db
    -- postgres.js
    -- redis.js
```

I would like to implement the cache at the models but I want to create the redis connection in `db/redis.js` and export it and have the model requiring it.

This is what `db/redis.js` looks like:

```js
const Redis = require('redis');
const redisClient = Redis.createClient();

redisClient.connect();

redisClient.on('connect', function() {
  console.log('Redis is Connected!');
});

redisClient.on('error', err => {
  console.log('Redis Error ' + err);
});

redisClient.on('end', () => {
  console.log('Redis disconnected');
});
redisClient.on('reconnecting', () => {
  console.log('Redis reconnecting');
});

module.exports = redisClient;
```

This is my model:

```js
const postgresClient = require('../db/postgres');
const redisClient = require('../db/redis');

const getAllUsers = (params, callback) => {
   console.log('getAllUsers');
   const page = params.page || 1;
   const count = params.count || 5;
   const offset = (page - 1) * count;
   const queryStr = `SELECT * FROM users OFFSET ${offset} FETCH NEXT ${count} ROWS ONLY`;
   const cacheKey = `\users?page=${page}&count=${count}`;

   redisClient.get(cacheKey, (error, users) => {
      console.log('redisClient.get');
      if (error) callback(error);
      if (users != null) {
         console.log('sending data from cache')  
         callback(null, JSON.parse(users));
      } else {
         postgresClient.query(queryStr, (err, res) => { 
            console.log('querying db and setting cache')
            if (err) callback(err);
            redisClient.setex(cacheKey, DEFAULT_EXPIRATION, JSON.stringify(res.rows))
            callback(null, res.rows);
         })
      }
   }
}
```

When I run the server and make a request to the endpoint that uses this model, the `console.log('getAllUsers');` runs but `console.log('redisClient.get');` doesn't.

It seems like the redis client `get callback` never executes and I wonder why.

Any help or advice is welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm facing a similar issue. Sounds like redis changed their interface a bit after v4.x.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me as if you're reinventing the world.  If what you want is just a cache, have you considered using a package for that?  I've had good luck with this one:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cacheman-redis

If that doesn't work for you, it looks like the latest version of the redis npm recommends using promises, like so:

```
const value = await redisClient.get(`key`);
if (!value) {
  // query postgres and set the value.  
}
```

If you just can't use await, then I'd suggest using then.  So, instead of using `redisClient.get(key, callback)` you could use

```
redisClient.get(key).then(successCallback).catch(failureCallback)
```

That being said, I **strongly** recommend looking at `cacheman-redis` and also becoming familiar with async/await functions and promises.  Each will simplify your code greatly.

Answer (score 0):

`redisClient.connect();` does not really wait before connection succeeds. If you are running the commands before it has a successful connection it wouldn't work. You need to wait before it's connected and then it's safe to run Redis commands.

You can remove `redisClient.connect();` from your `redis.js` file and use it in index.js where you connect it.

```js
const redisClient = require('../db/redis');
(async () => {
  await redisClient.connect();
  // Redis is connected and do your stuff below

})();
```

[example-source](https://github.com/redis/node-redis#basic-example)

Also, I'd recommend you to connect Redis at first and when successful then start the server.